# Why is there no way to "cross off" jobs in Stack Overflow Jobs?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs

When you're looking for a job you have to wade through a lot of positions that look good at first, but don't line up exactly.  It's rather annoying to have to wade through these jobs every day that you are job searching. This is why many job sites have some way to express "I'm not interested in this job", which then hides it from future search results.

Why doesn't Stack Overflow (the job site which should be the absolute best for programming job seekers) have a way to do this?

**EDIT:** Just to clarify: the accepted answer for the (**second edit:** former) "duplicate" of this question specifically states that it is *for job ads*.  Please understand that this question is not about job ads, but rather about jobs in the job search section of the site.  As far as I can tell there is no prior unanswered question for that topic, nor is there an answered question that deals with non-ad jobs.

Comment: When I'm ready to start searching for jobs again, now I know why I shouldn't use StackOverflow jobs (unless this feature is implemented by then). Thank you for pointing this out.

Comment: Also, if you don't mind editing it, could you add "and other notes about jobs" to your request?  It might be helpful to be able to search on our own custom items (like dev.isbored from the StackOverflow Jobs ad) that help us categorize.

Comment: hmmm... sounds like SO might have a job for you. :)

Comment: @NH. Sure we need more people getting the hump instead of trying to help get something improved...

Comment: I wish more sites had this feature. It would be excellent for Kickstarter, for instance.

Comment: Heck, even *Monster* sends me emails with job postings that include ones *I've already submitted my resume to.*

Comment: But sometime SO showing up and down thumb on right sidebar for companies or jobs. I think it is for companies.

Comment: Not looking for a job so I'm not really concerned, but at a quick glance it appears there is no upfront option to filter by "jobs posted in the last N days".  Which is surprising as it's an easy way to filter jobs you have already seen.

Comment: I don't think that other question is a duplicate. That says how to dismiss a job that appears in the little ad window on the main site. But it also says that you'll still see those jobs in the Jobs site. The Jobs site is what this question want to dismiss them from.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion :) the good news is: we have plans to work on this on the short term... so it should be done in... 6-8 weeks! (and you can't tell how much I'm enjoying the fact that the ETA is accurate)

Comment: Wow, that's really great news!  When you're job hunting it is SOOOOO helpful to be able to hide all the jobs that aren't relevant, instead of having to wade through them every day you look for new listings.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm happy to announce that this is now in prod!

We did a couple of things:

- Sync the jobs you dismissed on ads so that they're not shown on /jobs.
- Add the ability to dismiss jobs on /jobs (and those get synced to the ads system, so you won't see ads for them either)
- Add the ability to dismiss a company by its company page.

Regarding this last point (dismissing a company), we don't have the functionality to sync dismissed companies with ads. We will have it at some point (the infrastructure is there now). In the meantime, what we did is marking all those jobs as dismissed, so you shouldn't see jobs belonging to a company you dismissed on the ads.

There's one caveat though... if a dismissed company publishes a new job, that doesn't trigger a recalculation of dismissed jobs, so you may see for 24 hours (worst case scenario) the new job that belongs to a dismissed company.

We'll get there sooner rather than later.