# Stack Overflow Jobs Update - April 2018

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow-jobs

It’s been a while since the Jobs team has provided an update! There have been a lot of changes to our team structure and some new features released so it’s a good time to fill you in on what we’ve been up to.

## Team update

For the past couple of years we’ve had two teams dedicated to our Talent (formerly Careers) platform.  The “Jobs” team was focused on the candidate experience on [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/) while the “Talent” team was focused on the employer experience on [Stack Overflow Talent](http://talent.stackoverflow.com). Earlier this year we decided to merge product teams and take a more holistic approach with our product development. We also shifted our efforts for the first quarter on a few specific themes:

1. **Simplifying the employer experience** - there is a TON of legacy UX that just needed updating and our customers were finding it hard to carry out simple tasks. If you happen to be a Talent customer, then you’re probably familiar with how badly we needed to make some improvements here and hopefully you’re seeing some positive changes.
2. **Focus on user and customer feedback** - we wanted to make sure we dedicated major time to address pain points and requests from our job seekers and employers alike.

We felt that by merging teams to look at the product holistically and focusing on these key themes, we’d do a better job of delivering useful features and create a more meaningful experience for our users. We still have a lot of work to do but we feel good about this refresh in direction.

## New Features

Here’s a roundup of job seeker related features we recently shipped.

#### Saved searches

Instead of [automatically](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/350166/dont-automatically-create-a-recent-search-in-jobs) [storing](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/350962/do-not-create-recent-searches-for-intermediate-search-steps-in-jobs) your recent searches, you can now save the job searches you run most often. Saving a search will also create a job alert for you so you’ll get new jobs for the saved query to your inbox. You can manage saved searches and [job alerts](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/357481/add-back-ability-to-edit-job-alerts) in the right hand sidebar. This feature is also available on mobile web.

[image: saved searches]

#### Dismissing jobs & companies

You told us that [seeing](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358734/dismiss-company-ad-block-company-entirely) [the](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/357925/reject-single-job-recommendations-in-the-user-activity-tab) [same](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/356449/why-is-there-no-way-to-cross-off-jobs-in-stack-overflow-jobs) [jobs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359515/filter-out-jobs-applied-for-and-rejected-in-last-n-number-days) over and over can be frustrating. Now you can dismiss jobs or company pages. If you dismiss a job or a company, you will no longer see the job or company in search results. We also won’t recommend any of the jobs you dismissed through the various job recommendation channels (ads, emails, etc). To dismiss a job, you can hover over it to display the dismiss icon or click ‘dismiss’ from the the job listing itself. To dismiss a company, you can hover over the company in company search results or scroll to the bottom of a company page.

[image: dismiss-jobsearch]

[image: dismiss-companysearch]

#### Improved job recommendations

Job recommendations can be tricky. We’ve been testing and iterating on our matching algorithm [for a while now](https://stackoverflow.blog/2017/05/24/dive-stack-overflow-jobs-search/) and it’s something that we’ll continue to work on. It’s a hard thing to perfect, especially for new users or anonymous visitors who we know very little about. But some of you have [job preferences](https://stackoverflow.com/users/jobsearch/current) set so *you’ve told us* what you’re interested in.

We are now applying your job preferences as hard filters for job recommendations. This means that if you put `c#` and `c++` in your liked tags, only jobs which have either the `c#` tag or the `c++` tag will be recommended to you.  One caveat - this feature hasn’t been extended to job ads, which uses a different system entirely.

#### Better recommendation emails

When we launched our job recommendation emails, we [dropped](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358404/jobs-emails-we-really-like-this-job-for-you-arent-accurate-enough) [the](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/357869/feedback-about-we-like-this-job-for-you-email) [ball](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354588/we-really-like-this-job-for-you-annoying-emails). We heard loud and clear that they weren't targeted enough. So we worked on fixing them!
Now, we only send a recommended job if it matches all your job preferences, and we also explain in the email why that job was emailed to you.

[image: email recommendation]

#### Express interest

We heard a common theme in user research with job seekers: applying to jobs is time consuming and it’s a pain to fill out application forms. So we’re testing out a new feature we’re calling Express Interest. This is a time-saving feature to quickly let employers know you’re interested in a role. 
When you express interest in a job, the employer will either see your Developer Story, if it’s minimally completed, or the resume you’ve saved to your job preferences.
As mentioned, we’re testing this feature out and it’s not available on every job. We’ll keep iterating as we learn more but the goal is to give you an easier way to connect with employers around opportunities that pique your interest.

[image: express interest]

## Coming up (in 6-8 weeks)

Here are a few things slated for the near term:

#### Better labeling for remote jobs

[Remote jobs](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/remote-developer-jobs) is by far the most popular job search. However, there are [some nuances](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359361/more-specific-labels-than-remote) in how employers define a remote position which might impact your decision to apply. For example, the company allows you to work fully remote but you must be located in a specific region or time zone. Or perhaps the company only allows you to work remotely a percentage of the time. So we’ll be updating the form employers fill out for job listings to support better remote job labeling.

#### Company page improvements

We simply haven’t updated company pages much since it launched a few years ago. Our customers have been asking for better ways to illustrate what their tech teams are doing. Job seekers have also expressed that they want to [gain more insight](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358169/allow-qa-on-company-pages) on the hiring process, dev culture, team dynamics, and products for companies they are interested in. So we’ve prioritized this as an area we want to make more useful for both job seekers and employers.

#### Job Syndication

Another common complaint we’ve heard time and again is that we don’t have enough jobs. Our mission is to help the *world’s* developers in finding their next opportunity but how can we if we don’t have enough jobs *around the world*? 
We’ve considered several solutions to address the limited number of jobs on our platform and we’ve decided to explore job syndication. We’re testing out partnerships with platforms that have a large share of developer jobs, especially in regions where we don’t have a lot of jobs, and allowing them to syndicate their listings on our site. We’re planning a series of experiments on this front, so you may come across listings where you are taken to one of our partner sites to complete your application. Based on the data and learnings from these tests, we’ll decide whether this is something we should pursue further and optimize.

And of course, we’ll continue to focus on feedback from you to prioritize features that will make Jobs more useful. <3

Comment: Is there any way to un-dismiss a job or company if they are accidentally dismissed?

Comment: @numaroth Yes. Immediately after you click dismiss on a job or company, there will be an undo link in case you accidentally clicked dismiss.

Comment: It would be useful to be able to un-dismiss them further into the future, when your job interests change and you are more willing to consider those jobs/companies.

Answer (score 10):

Is there any reason that the jobs email is so poorly targeted?

> We have found new jobs that match your interests

No you didn't, you included a bunch of jobs with tags specified in my ignore list.

eg. although you know I have never viewed, let alone answered, any iOS/OSX questions and you know I have never accessed your site with any Apple device - you send me a job requiring expert level iOS knowledge.

Comment: it seems like [you have an alert for all new jobs](https://stackoverflow.com/users/email/job-alerts/current). By definition, we're not targeting those. You probably want to delete that one (the ones we're targeting are the recommendations ones). I'll propose changing the copy... it would be clearer if it mentioned that the email is sent due to an alert on your account.

Comment: I have the form fully filled out - tech I like, tech I avoid, location and salary range. But perhaps because I clicked remote it also lists  jobs from anywhere in the world with any tech

Comment: I turned off the daily alert, but it is immediately under a line which says "New jobs that match your criteria." so I assumed there was some filtering

Comment: yeah, we’ll tweak the copy to make it really clear that the email was sent due to an alert. Thanks for bringing this up!