# What is the status of "Express Interest" feature?

Tags: support, stack-overflow-jobs

Back in June-July, when I was searching through the Stack Overflow Jobs I would see the "Express Interest" button in most of the jobs' page (even I used it one time and heard back from the employer). However, recently I have never seen it even once in the jobs I am interested in. Since in [Stack Overflow Jobs Update - April 2018](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/366714/2099607) it was stated that:

> So we’re testing out a new feature we’re calling Express Interest...
>   As mentioned, we’re testing this feature out and it’s not available on
>   every job. We’ll keep iterating as we learn more but the goal is to
>   give you an easier way to connect with employers around opportunities
>   that pique your interest.

I was wondering whether this feature still continues to exist or it has been removed entirely? Specifically:

- If it currently exists, what has been the feedback so far? Will it be available for all the jobs in the future? And Is there any timeline for its full deployment?
- or If it has been removed, what has been the reasons?

Comment: Last week I received a message from an employer about a job and it had "I'm interested" button at the end of the message. So it seems it's still in place. When I go to the job listing's page I also see the same button so it's probably up to them to enable that button.

Comment: @ayhan Thanks. "...so it's probably up to them to enable that button." you mean the employer decides to whether enable it for their job?

Comment: Yes I think so. Because I don't see it in other listings. It might also be an A/B testing thing too.

Comment: @ayhan The "interested/not interested" button on the message *from* an employer is different. All messages you get sent have that button as its a quick way to say "tell me more" or "no thanks" without having to actually type anything (on the other side: the resulting message is not great and I found out yesterday that you HAVE to click one of them if you want to tell the employer anything! i.e. "Thanks for reaching out, but I got a job recently, so I'm not available" or "Thanks, but my skill set is more X than Y.")

Answer (score 4):

Express Interest continues to exist on a subset of jobs. We get decent amount of usage on it and an interesting trend we noticed is that most users who express interest in a job end up applying to it shortly afterwards.

We have a few ideas for improvements that we hope to explore. These range from building out an “Easy Apply” feature, better support for asking questions on a listing, and the ability to express interest in a company instead of a specific listing.

However, we don’t have a concrete timeline for this as yet.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The idea of being able to express interest in a company sounds really interesting to me. I think it's a very useful feature.